# How can I add a shebang to file in a specific directory

Tags: vimrc

I need to configure vim to add the shebang `#!/bin/bash` if the edited file is in the directory `/usr/bin/` and if it is empty (or even better if it doesn't exist)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to add the shebang to any new file in `/usr/bin/`:

```
func Shebang(path)
    echo a:path
    if a:path =~ "/usr/bin/[^/]*"
        normal i#!/bin/bash
    endif
endfunc
autocmd BufNewFile /usr/bin/* execute Shebang(expand('<amatch>'))
```

This will only execute on new files, and also ensures the file isn't in a subdirectory in `/usr/bin`.  You could also modify it so the pattern of `*.sh` (a new shell file created anywhere) also gets the shebang.  If you don't care about subdirectories and only want this to every work in `/usr/bin`, you could also just do:

```
autocmd BufNewFile /usr/bin/* normal i#!/bin/bash
```